# How can I use the PERIOD feature of Temporal Postgres / Postgres 9.2 on Heroku?

Tags: postgresql, datetime, heroku, timestamp, postgresql-9.2

I am building an app that deals with times and durations, and intersections between given units of time and start/end times in a database, for example:

Database:

```
Row # | start - end
Row 1 | 1:00 - 4:00
Row 2 | 3:00 - 6:00
```

I want to be able to select sums of time between two certain times, or GROUP BY an INTERVAL such that the returned recordset will have one row for each sum during a given interval, something like:

```
SELECT length( (start, end) )  WHERE (start, end) INTERSECTS (2:00,4:00)
```

(in this case (start,end) is a PERIOD which is a new data type in Postgres Temporal and pg9.2)

which would return

```
INTERVAL 3 HOURS
```

since Row 1 has two hours between 2:00 - 4:00 and Row 2 has one hour during that time.

further, i'd like to be able to:

```
SELECT "lower bound of start", length( (start, end) )  GROUP BY INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

which i would like to return:

```
1:00 | 1
2:00 | 1
3:00 | 2
4:00 | 2
5:00 | 1
```

which shows one row for each hour during the given interval and the sum of time at the beginning of that interval

I *think* that the PERIOD type can be used for this, which is in Postgres Temporal and Postgres 9.2.  However, these are not available on Heroku at this time as far as I can tell - So,

How can I enable these sorts of maths on Heroku?

Comment: Can't really reply to you but, afaik, the temporal extension has been very poorly supported and documented as the work has been used to create the tsrange in Pg 9.2. This means it didn't even come with the official Postgres's contribs in 9.1 so I think there are few chances you can load this extension in Heroku for now.

Comment: Like @greg says, the temporal extension is a precursor to the range types incorporated into PostgreSQL 9.2. I would wait for 9.2 if at all possible. You are likely to find exclusion constraints useful when using range columns.

Answer (score 1):

Try running:

```
 heroku addons:add heroku-postgresql:dev --version=9.2
```

That should give you the 9.2 version which has range types supported. As this is currently very alpha any feedback would be greatly appreciated at dod-feedback@heroku.com